# Cannot find index.js file in React-Bootstrap Module

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, node-modules, react-bootstrap

Been trying to install and use a ReactJS UI library and keep getting a compilation error. It seems that the entry file cannot be found for the modules. I get the same error with the material-ui library.

```html
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Button extends Component {

render() {
        return (        
                    <Button>Button</Button>
        );
    }
}
```

**Error :**

Cannot find file: 'index.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: 'C:\Users......\node_modules\react-bootstrap\esm\repos'.

Any help would be much appreciated thanks!